# simplexml_load_string and child nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to get the information out of an xml string and view the child nodes in it.  I am using:

```
'Title' => $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2')->ItemAttributes->Title,
```

in an array where $current

```
$current = $parsed_xml->ListMatchingProductsResponse->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product;
```

the namespace is ns2 and the children are ItemAttributes and Title.  When I run this I get no information where the title should be.  Here is the response when I run the script:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?  I have looked at the other posts and have tried to use their examples but they are not working for me.
Here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListMatchingProductsResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<ListMatchingProductsResult>
<Products xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
<Product>
<AttributeSets>
<ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="en-US">
<ns2:Title>JavaScript: The Missing Manual</ns2:Title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs to do something similar, the correct way to get the children information is:

```
'Title' => $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->Title,
```

String is not needed, but true is.

Answer (score 0):

You generally need to cast simpleXml elements to a string to get the value out.  Try 
`'Title' => (string)$current->AttributeSets->children('ns2')->ItemAttributes->Title`

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to remove the namespace ns2 before putting it through simplexml_load_string with a simple string replace, i think it's kind of a hack but it's how i do it.

```
$response = str_replace('ns2:', '', $response);
$parse_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```